# How to automatically set a field's value when creating a new record in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails noob here. I have a rails application with (in this example) three tables. Users, Machines, and Tests.

Users have many Machines and Tests.

Machines belong to Users.

Tests belong to Machines.

When I create a new test, I want the field test.machine_id to automatically be set to the id of the machine that owns that test. I have been able to create a field with a drop-down menu showing all machines owned by current_user, but I don't want the user to have to set this field manually.

Tests can only be created by accessing a "create new test" link on a Machine Show page.

*For example, User 1 has Machines 4 and 5. When viewing Machine 5's Show page, I want to create test 10. I want test(10).machine_id to be set to 5 without a user having to enter this manually.*

In my tests_controller.rb file, I have the following:

```
 def new
@test = Test.new
@machines = current_user.machiness.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @test }
end
end


 def create
@test = Test.new(params[:test])

respond_to do |format|
  if @test.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@test, :notice => 'Test was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @test, :status => :created, :location => @test }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @test.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I imagine I need something like:

```
def create
@test = current_machine.tests.build(params[:test])
...
end
```

...but I don't think current_machine is an actual object.

Tests can only be created by accessing a "create new test" link on a Machine Show page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a nested resource for your `Test` model.  In your routes file, you would set up your resources like this:

```
resources :machines do
  resources :tests
end
```

This will make the route for a new `Test` look like `/machines/:machine_id/tests/new`.  So now your link to the new Test page would look something like

```
<%= link_to "New Test", new_machine_tests_path(@machine) %>
```

and your `new` action in `TestsController` would be something like

```
def new
  @test = Test.new
  @machine = Machine.find(params[:machine_id])
  ...
end
```

Finally, the form for your nested `Test` resource would be something like

```
<%= form_for [@machine, @test] do |f| %>
...
```

That sets up the form to post to a path that will automatically include your machine_id, something `/machines/123/tests`.

So in the `create` action of your `TestsController` you can do something like

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(params[:test])
  @test.machine_id = params[:machine_id]
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes! This is perfect. I can't thank you enough.

StackOverflow is surely a gift from God.

Answer (score 1):

```
@test = Test.new(params[:test])
@test.your_field = 'default value'
```

or change filed in database to set default value:

```
change_column :tests, :your_column, :string, :default => 'default value'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The only problem is that I don't want to set a default value. I want @test.machine_id to automatically be set to the machine_id of the machine>show page I just came from.

I added an example above to clarify.

Comment: So use first method: `@test.machine_id = params[:machine_id]`

Comment: Awesome. Almost there.

So adding    @test.machine_id = params[:machine_id] is setting machine_id to 1, regardless of which machine>show page I come from.

How can I make sure that the :machine_id that is used is the :machine_id of the show page from which I came?

Thanks again!

Comment: It's defined by route. You can check it by typing `rake routes` in console and see all routes, when some part is started with `:` then it is a symbol passed to `params` hash.